# How can I implement MATLAB parallel computing on more than one node

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

On a supercomputing server, I assign a task to 2 nodes, with 48 workers maximum.

But the MATLAB command `parpool(36)` does not work. The error message is as follows:

> Error using parpool (line 113)
>   You requested a minimum of 36 workers, but the cluster "local" has the NumWorkers property set to allow a maximum of 24 workers. To run a communicating job on more workers than this (up to a maximum of 512 for the Local cluster), increase the value of the NumWorkers property for the cluster. The default value of NumWorkers for a Local cluster is the number of cores on the local machine.

According to this tip, I added two commands to my code as shown below:

```matlab
myCluster = parcluster;
myCluster.NumWorkers = 36;
```

After that, `parpool(36)` runs without errors, but the computing time remains unchanged. So I guess that these 2 commands can't help me. How can I use 36 cores on 2 nodes?

Comment: maybe your code is not correct, but we cant know, you shared no code

Comment: Are you telling MATLAB which modes it can run on? It looks like you’re computing on a single node.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as written is using the "local" cluster type in MATLAB. This is designed to run on the cores of a single machine. If you want to run on a "real" cluster, you need to submit a job (or launch a `parpool`) using a cluster profile that submits to a [MATLAB Parallel Server](https://uk.mathworks.com/products/matlab-parallel-server.html) cluster.

For instance, if you want to use an existing cluster that is running SLURM, you would follow the instructions [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab-parallel-server/integrate-matlab-with-third-party-schedulers.html) to install stuff and then [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab-parallel-server/configure-parallel-computing-products-for-supported-third-party-schedulers-pbs-pro-platform-lsf-torque.html) to set up a cluster profile. Once you've got a cluster profile of this sort, you can either submit a `batch` job to run there like so:

```
clus = parcluster('my slurm profile');
j = batch(@myFunction, 3, {in1, in2}, 'Pool', 36); % 3 is nargout for myFunction
```

Or you can run an interactive pool on your client accessing the cluster like so

```
parpool('my slurm profile', 36);
```